# PowerBuilder/VB Development: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: visual-studio, http, powerbuilder

Getting this error executing an HTTP request. TLS 1.0 (Server) is disabled. TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are both enabled. I can execute the same query using Postman with no error. The error I am getting is: (The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted). I get the error running code from either PowerBuilder or Visual Basic.

Comment: Get the same error executing on 2 different workstations. 1 is a server behind a firewall/dmz, the other my desktop behind my personal firewall.

Comment: What exactly are you executing? Could you provide the code?